# Determining if the screen gets too small to display the page

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to detect when the user resizes the screen below a certain width and height and show a div with a message (in a div) saying the window has become too small to properly display the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var resizeTimer;

function nagOnResize() {
    //pause for 1/4 of a second to see if the window stopped moving
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(doNagOnResize, 250);
}

function doNagOnResize() {
    $(window).unbind('resize', nagOnResize); //pause the event
    var h = $(window).height(), w = $(window).width();
    if(w < 300) {
        alert("< 300px wide");
    }
    $(window).resize(nagOnResize); //continue the event
};

$(window).resize(nagOnResize);
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/FWhgT/

Comment: The `unbind` suggested here seems pointless... Also - Ben Alman has a [throttle/debounce](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/jquery-throttle-debounce-v11/) plugin that makes doing the "timeout" pretty trivial.  You might want to check it out, its super tiny.

Comment: The `unbind()` is to avoid queuing up more events while the `alert()` is visible, and blocking. Otherwise you may get a whole slew of them (pointlessly) after clicking OK. By pausing the event you will only get one.

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like

```
var nagOnResize = function() {
    var h = $(window).height(), w = $(window).width();
    // change the condition as needed
    if(w < 300) {
        // make it $("#nag").show(); if you want
        alert("< 300px wide");
    }
    // Recursive call. Not binding to $(window).resize as it's fired way too many times on some browsers
    setTimeout(nagOnResize, 100);
};

nagOnResize();
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ajVpG/1/ (Decrease browser width to make the Result iframe < 300px)

Comment: Please don't do that, you are calling this function 10 times per second! Even when the window is not being resized. Use $(window).resize - that's what it's for. If you think it's being called to much add a delay, otherwise your cure is worse than the disease. I will post an edited version in a new answer.